# Как отослать сообщение пользователю в браузер в случае ошбики при выполнении валидации параметров роута?

Tags: laravel

Я использую глобальный способ валидации параметров роута:

```
public function boot()
{
    //Router parameters patterns
    Route::pattern('startId', '[0-9]+');
    Route::pattern('endId', '[0-9]+');

    parent::boot();
}
```

Я не понимаю как:

1) сделать так что бы в случае нахождения ошибки в переданных через параметры роута данных можно было бы отослать сообщение в виде JSON объекта на машину пользователя.

2) хотелось бы иметь возможность исправить тип генерируемой ошибки. Сейчас при такой форме валидации, при каждой ошибке, всегда генерируется одна и та же ошибка типа NotFoundHttpException.

3) В Laravel есть какой то более удобный способ валидирования входящих параметров хранимых в строке роута? (Например как при валидации переданных JSON данных с использованием Request)

Comment: Зачем это делать ? если роута нету, то и так будет ошибка, что б тип был json нужно посылать заголовки, `'HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'`

Comment: + ты можешь делать необходимую проверку прям в файле где задаешь маршрут  `Route::get('example/{id}/{name}', function ($id, $name) {})->where(['id' => '[0-9]+', 'name' => '[a-z]+']);`

Comment: @Orange_shadow Просто думая наперед, хотел предусмотреть возможность, показать пользователю текст ошибки с указанием причин. Вместо непонятного текста на английском. Я не знал с какой стороны подойти к реализации вопроса технически. Сначала меня посетила мысль в случае возникновения ошибки отсылать пользователю json объект с текстом ошибки. Но по прошествии времени, я изменил подход. Судя по всему наверное правильнее было бы сделать какой то HTML компонент с текстом, который бы показывался пользователю в результате ошибки на исходящий из браузера XMLHttpRequest (я использую vue-resourse)

Comment: @Orange_shadow Вышеизложенные мысли по поводу компонента с текстом ошибки для пользователя наверное применимы к get запросу. Но POST PUTCH  я так понимаю все равно нужно обращатся к варианту с отсылкой текста в виде JSON объекта с сервера клиету.

Comment: @Orange_shadow В общем немного не могу выработать удобный и понятный подход к обработке ошибок возникающих на сервере в результате валидации параметров строки запроса, либо данных переданных в заголовках.

Comment: Почитайте про валидацию через middleware и $this->validate в контроллере, третий параметр метода validate($data,$rules,$message) - как раз сообщение которые вы можете переопределить, например: ['name.require'=>'Имя обязательно для заполнения'] , если вы не пройдете валидацию, а в заголовках будет указан application/json, то вы получаете ошибку 420 и массив с описанием ошибок